# AJAX PHP Private messages

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hi I want to make a simple private messager in PHP, MySQL, JavaScript and probably AJAX but I dont really know where to start. Does anyone know of any good relatively simple tutorials to create one...it doesn't need to be complex, just an extremely basic one for functionality. Thanks for any replies :)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is just a buzz word, whether or not you are using it when you are using JavaScript is a matter of definition. Anyway, what methods and languages are you familiar with?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but given the way you ask I presume that you are not a lot into any of the stuff, in which case you should probably start with something a little simple. It's not that it is such a terribly hard task programming wise, it just has a lot of tedious setup and requires multiple different languages interfacing, meaning that bug-tracking may be hard.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a tutorial, but a guy created a web based chat app using node.js for the messaging and php to serve up the pages. He recently open sourced it: https://github.com/isaacsu/twich